# Adding a string (with only digits in it) to a number results in a number (according to isNaN) which looks like it should have been a string?

Tags: javascript

1) Why the 155100 is a number here? Just like 255 would be if `var s = 155;`.

2) Why the 155100 is still a number even if `var n = "100";` ?

3) Where and why is `var res` converted to a number?

What am I missing here?

```js
var s = "155";
var n = 100;
var res = s + n;
document.write(res + "<hr>");
if ( isNaN(res) ) {
    document.write("It is not a number");
}
if ( !isNaN(res) ) {
    document.write("It is a number");
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>stackoverflow.com</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: You seem to be confusing `isNaN` and `typeof`, one checks if something is  specifically Not-A-Number, the other checks if something is of type Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your questions:

1. *Why the 155100 is a number here? Just like 255 would be if `var s = 155`;?*

   It is a string, but when passed to `isNaN`, that function coerces it to a number and then returns whether that coercion resulted in `NaN`.
2. *Why the 155100 is still a number even if `var n = "100";`?*

   See above. It is not.
3. *Where and why is `var res` converted to a number?*

   It is not -- it remains a string.

But as documented [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN#Description):

> When the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type `Number`, the value is first coerced to a `Number`.

#### Notes

To check if a variable is of the `Number` type:

```
if (typeof res === 'number')
```

To convert a string to a number, one of these:

```
i = +res;
i = Number(res);
```

If you want to only check the start of a string, and not fail if any subsequent characters are not numeric (like `123.45abc`), then use:

```
i = parseFloat(res);
```

If your interest is only in integers, you can use `parseInt`, preferably with the second argument to indicate the base. Like with `parseFloat`, it does not return `NaN` as soon as the first character passes the test:

```
i = parseInt(res, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

`isNaN` will always return `false` for a string value regardless of whether or not it can be parsed into a valid number. In order to check if your string is a valid number, you can parse it with `parseInt` and check if the result is `NaN`:

```
var s = "155";
var n = 100;
var res = s + n;
document.write(res + "<hr>");
if ( isNaN(parseInt(res)) ) {
    document.write("It is not a number");
} else {
    document.write("It is a number");
}
```

Note: `parseInt` will only return `NaN` if the first character cannot be converted to a number. MDN has a "stricter" version [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#A_stricter_parse_function) that returns `NaN` if any part of the string cannot be converted .

Comment: > isNaN specifically checks if a value is equal to NaN - not true: try isNaN('q')

Answer (score 0):

See the MDN link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```
isNaN(res) ---> will be false because 155100 is numeric

typeof res ---> string
```

Go ahead - try it in your Chrome console right now.

```
typeof "155100"
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a language based upon loose type-interpretation, instead of implicitly requiring type declaration or throwing an error else-wise;

When JavaScript gets a something in quotes, it determines it to be a string; the `+` operator, with the type now being `String`, is understood by JavaScript in this context as a string concatenater (concatenation is the combination of two or more things things) and so it happily appends the two together.

Here, you need to do what is known as **Type Casting** or **Type Throwing** where you throw(or cast) something into a different type. This is necessary here so that your `+` operator will behave as you desire

For Example:

```
var str = "3.14";
var num = new Number(str);
```

The `new` keyword is optional, but is recommended for source clarity and readability.